# Show that the sequence $\{\int^1_0 \cos^2(t/n) dt\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is convergent and find the limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Show that the sequence $\{\int^1_0 \cos^2(t/n) dt\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is convergent and find the limit.

I've verified that $\{\cos(t/n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for $t \in [0,1]$ converges uniformly to $1$.

Also I've tried to compute the anti-derivative of $\cos^2(t/n): \int \cos^2(t/n) dt = \frac {n\sin(2/n)} 4 + \frac 1 2$.

But how can I conclude this sequence is convergent ?

Comment: Do you know any consequences of uniform convergence concerning integrals?

Comment: Yeah, but in order to use this, I must show $\cos^2(t/n)$ converge uniformly. Does $\cos(t/n)$ converge uniformly imply $\cos^2(t/n)$ converge uniformly ?

Comment: Mind if I ask what $\{f(x)\}_{x=a}^b$ means?  I've not seen this notation before.

Comment: It is just an ordinary sequence of numbers that starts at index $a$ and goes to $\infty$. Here $x$ denote a value in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Oh so it's basically $\{f(a)\,..\,f(b)\}$, I can see how that would be cumbersome to write here.  Danke

Comment: ...but you could write $\{f(x) \mid x \in a .. b\}$ also...

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos^2(1/n)\leqslant\int_0^1\cos^2(t/n)\,\mathrm dt\leqslant1$$

Comment: Thank you @Did. Is there some easy way of showing $\cos^2(t/n)$ converge uniformly by a consequence that $\cos(t/n)$ converge uniformly on $[0,1]$ and thereby apply a sweet theorem regarding integration.

Comment: No further theorem needed, this answer is fully self-contained. It is based on the fact that, for every $t$ in $[0,1]$, $\cos^2(t/n)$ is in $[\cos^2(1/n),1]$. Since $\cos^2(1/n)\to1$, this implies uniform convergence, if you insist on using it.